# Not Able to write a dataframe from local machine using pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, anaconda

I am trying to write a dataframe to some local path in my system using pyspark in csv format.

Using below code to write.

```
df2.write.format("csv").save("C:\\Users\\ms\\OneD\\sa_ds\\interim\\cusm_iop",header=True )
```

But I am getting below error.

```
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-f0dd4df118cb> in <module>()
----> 1 df2.write.format("csv").save("C:\\Users\\ms\\OneDrive - UHG\\sas_ds\\interim\\customer_int",header=True )

C:\SPARKMEDIA\spark-2.4.7-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\sql\readwriter.py in save(self, path, format, mode, partitionBy, **options)
    737             self._jwrite.save()
    738         else:
--> 739             self._jwrite.save(path)
    740 
    741     @since(1.4)

C:\Users\ms\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\py4j\java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1255         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1256         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1257             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1258 
   1259         for temp_arg in temp_args:

C:\SPARKMEDIA\spark-2.4.7-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\sql\utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
     61     def deco(*a, **kw):
     62         try:
---> 63             return f(*a, **kw)
     64         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
     65             s = e.java_exception.toString()

C:\Users\ms\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\py4j\protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329             else:
    330                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o80.save.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:198)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:159)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:104)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:102)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:122)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:83)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:81)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:696)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:696)
    ...
```

tried a lot find the issue but didn't found. Can anyone suggest what to do?

Comment: Is it possible that there was a larger stack trace at the bottom where you wrote `...`? If yes, could you add that please?

Comment: Works fine for me, did the directory "customer_int" aleady exist in your machine, also did you download the winutils.exe and hadoop.dll of your hadoop version "2.7" and set up HADOOP_HOME

Comment: @AbdennacerLachiheb,  customer_int directory is not present before and also i have downloaded winutils. Also added to environmental variables (HADOOP_HOME)

Comment: @Koedlt, I am not able to add full error.
Caused by: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.errors.package$TreeNodeException: execute, tree:
Exchange rangepartitioning(cust_detail_ky#10 ASC NULLS FIRST, 200)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 55

above are high level error.

Comment: Why can't you add the full error? In any case, the python error messages are less interesting than the Java stack trace, so we're missing the crucial part here.

Answer (score 0):

why are you not using .csv at the end of your file?

```
df2.write.format("csv").save("C:\\Users\\ms\\OneD\\sa_ds\\interim\\cusm_iop.csv",header=True )
```

Comment: spark will create multiple files where actual data file will have .csv extension.

Comment: Spark doesn't care for extension, for him it just a directory with or without .csv at the end